# Removing a Command from an Xcode Build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to open a Swift 2 project using Xcode 8.2.1.

I've changed a couple of things in order to get it to work, namely adding pods for Alamofire.

I am now able to successfully use

```
import Alamofire
```

And it checks fine.

However, there is a horrible error on build attempt:

```
  PBXCp /Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cydfykckqtyklyfbipzafsqlmxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework /Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cydfykckqtyklyfbipzafsqlmxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
      cd /Users/billybob/dev/viablelabs-MyApp-ios-e26ff0e163b3
      export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
      builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -exclude Headers -exclude PrivateHeaders -exclude Modules -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cydfykckqtyklyfbipzafsqlmxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework /Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cydfykckqtyklyfbipzafsqlmxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Frameworks

  error: /Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cydfykckqtyklyfbipzafsqlmxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory
```

Other's suggest to delete these folders, re-open Xcode and clean/build which I have tried many times.

Instead I think this error is from the previous developer's attempt at getting Alamofire working.

Where can I find this command so I can delete it and get a free build.

Comment: Path is there - " /Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"

Comment: The error is that it's trying to find AlamoFire.framework and isn't finding it.  Deleting the DerivedData folder is definitely a good place to start (/Users/billybob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData).  Assuming that doesn't work, find the AlamoFire.framework and drag it into your project, clean, and build.

Comment: For some reason the framework actually is in Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework 
I'll try dragging to project first.

Answer (score 0):

remove Alamofire and reinstall Alamofire for swift 3

Comment: This project is using Swift 2

Comment: sorry in Xcode 8.2 Swift 3 will work so you should reinstall Alamofire for Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

To delete the data you just need to run in the terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```